# Avoid MySQL Injection and XSS

Tags: xss, sql-injection

Is this way secured to insert data to DB ?

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripcslashes($_POST["address"]), ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: no. it's not. you're using an obsolete DB library. You're trashing your data by specialchars/stripslashes on it as well.

Comment: There is no "silver bullet".  But arguably one of the most effective ways to guard against SQL injection is to use prepared statements:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: In this answer 

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

The second answer said: 

> //Connect

$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"]
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $safe_variable . "')");

//Disconnect

that means i need to use $var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]); only ? and to print like this 

echo htmlspecialchars($row['address']);

**OPD** is an advanced option, i'm a newbie, don't really understand.

Comment: magic quotes is enabled, can i use like this ? $var = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST["address"]));

Answer (score 2):

There is no "silver bullet".

But arguably one of the most effective ways to guard against SQL injection is to use prepared statements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Another, equally effective defense is to use the most modern, secure mySql APIs available: either mySqli (object-oriented) or PDO SQL:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Here is a link good link regarding SQL Injection, and how you can mitigate risks in your mySql code:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Two guidelines I would strongly urge you to follow:

1) You should *NOT* use the old, deprecated mySql API for any new code.  Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

2) You should *NOT* allow raw user input anywhere near a SQL statement.  Carefully validate your input, and use prepared statements whenever possible.

IMHO...

Comment: The question was directed at XSS as well, where I would just add to use htmlspecialchars when you outputting from a DB, not when you are inserting it